# Value of $~~a~~$ for which $~~2+\sqrt 3~~$ is a root of $~~f$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, roots, cubics

Let us consider a function $~~f(x)=x^3-5x^2+ax-1.~$ Find the value of $~~a~~$ for which $~~2+\sqrt 3~~$ is a root of $~~f$.

**My attempt:** First way is to put the value $~~x=2+\sqrt 3~~$ in $~~f(x)=0~~$ and evaluate the value of $~~a~~$ which is $~~5.$ But this process is very calculative (Since I am getting only $~~1$ min  for each questions in this exam).
Next way is more calculative than this, in which I have consider $~~z,~w~~$ are  roots of $~f~$ other than $~~2+\sqrt 3.~~$ Then we have
$$z+w+2+\sqrt 3=5~~~\text{ and }~~~zw=\frac{1}{2+\sqrt 3}.$$
Then by solving aforesaid equation, one of $~z~$ or $~w~$ is $~1~$ and $~~f(1)=0~$ gives $~~a=5.$

Now my question, is there any other simple or easier method to solve this? Because the exam in which this question belongs gives a slight less than $~~1$ min  for each questions.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Vague recollection, if $a+\sqrt{b}$ is a root of a polynomial with rational coefficients, $a-\sqrt{b}$ is a root as well. Taking this into account and using your second pair of equations, the other roots are $2-\sqrt{3}$ and 1. Given those roots, I think you can solve for $a$.

Comment: Is $a\in Q$?, please edit your question.

Comment: @LionHeart noting is given about $~a,~~$ all I know $~a \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: There is no need to assume that $a$ is rational $-$ it only has one possible value. The proof is elementary $-$ see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to guess that the polynomial has all rational coefficients (i.e. $a\in\mathbb{Q}$). Then apply the irrational root theorem (I think this is what the name is) to conclude that if $2+\sqrt{3}$ is a root, then so is its conjugate, $2-\sqrt{3}$.

Hence we have that
$$\begin{cases}z+2-\sqrt{3}+2+\sqrt{3}=5\\z(2+\sqrt{3})(2-\sqrt{3})=1\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} z+4=5\\ z(1)=1\end{cases}$$
Since there does exist a solution, $z=1$, to this system of equations, our assumption was correct.

We can then calculate, using vieta's, that
$$a=z(2-\sqrt{3})+z(2+\sqrt{3})+(2-\sqrt{3})(2+\sqrt{3})$$
$$a=4z+1$$
$$a=\boxed{5}$$

Comment: This is unnecessary! See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If $x^3-5x^2+ax-1=0$, then $x$ can't be zero. So we can divide by it and rearrange, to get
$$a=-x^2+5x+\frac{1}{x}$$
Now just put $x=2+\sqrt 3$ to get $a$, using
$$-x^2=-7-4\sqrt 3$$
$$5x=10+5\sqrt 3$$
$$\frac{1}{x}=2-\sqrt 3$$
Easy!

Comment: Nice solution. I agree that this is more rigorous than mine as it doesn't require one to guess that the polynomial is rational.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x^3-5x^2+ax-1$$
$$f(2+\sqrt 3)=0$$

Doing synthetic division,

\begin{array}{r|r|r|r|r}
            & 1 &          -5 &            a & -1\\
\sqrt 3 + 2 & 0 & \sqrt 3 + 2 & -\sqrt 3 - 3 & (2a-9)+(a-5)\sqrt 3\\ 
\hline
            & 1 & \sqrt 3-3   & -\sqrt 3 +(a-3) & (2a-10)+(a-5)\sqrt 3
\end{array}

$$(2a-10)+(a-5)\sqrt 3 = (a-5)(2+\sqrt 3) = 0 \implies a=5$$

Which means we need to have $a=5$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $2 + \sqrt{3}$ is a root of $x^2 - 4x + 1$, we can consider dividing the original polynomial $f$ by $x^2 - 4x + 1$, and $2 + \sqrt{3}$ will be a root of $f$ if and only if it is a root of the remainder.  If we do so, then $x^3 \equiv 4x^2 - x \pmod{x^2 - 4x + 1}$, so
$$f \equiv -x^2 + (a-1) x - 1 \pmod{x^2-4x+1}.$$
Now, adding $x^2 - 4x + 1$, we see also
$$f \equiv (a-5)x \pmod{x^2-4x+1}.$$
From here, we see that $2 + \sqrt{3}$ is a root of $f$ if and only if it is a root of $(a-5)x$, which is equivalent to
$$(a-5) (2+\sqrt{3}) = 0.$$
Since $2 + \sqrt{3} \ne 0$, we see this is further equivalent to $a = 5$.

(So here, the idea is that dividing by $x^2 - 4x + 1$ is simpler than dividing by $x - (2 + \sqrt{3})$ for manual calculations, where the latter is computationally equivalent to evaluating $f(2 + \sqrt{3})$.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way that doesn't involve *too* much computation is to "shift" the polynomial to avoid taking powers of a sum of an integer and an irrational number.  Taking $ \ u \ = \ x - 2 \ \rightarrow \ x \ = \ u + 2 \ \ , $ the binomial expansions are
$$ (u+2)^3 \ - \ 5·(u+2)^2 \ + \ a·(u+2) \ - \ 1 $$
$$ = \ \ (u^3 \ + \ 3·u^2·2 \ + \ 3·u·2^2 \ + \ 2^3) \ - \ 5·(u^2\ + \ 4u \ + \ 4)  \ + \  (au \ + \ 2a) \ - \ 1 $$
$$ = \ \  u^3 \ + \ (6 \ - \ 5)·u^2  \ + \ (12 \ - \ 20 \ + \ a)·u \ + \ (8 \ - \ 20 \ + 2a \ - \ 1 )  $$
$$ = \ \  u^3 \ + \ u^2  \ + \ ( a \ - \ 8)·u \ + \ ( 2a \ - \ 13 ) \ \ .  $$
We now want to evaluate this at $ \ u \ = \ \sqrt3 \ $ to find the value(s) of $ \ a \ $ for which
$$ (\sqrt3)^3 \ + \ (\sqrt3)^2  \ + \ ( a \ - \ 8)·(\sqrt3) \ + \ ( 2a \ - \ 13 ) \ \ = \ \ 0    $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 3·\sqrt3 \ + \ 3  \ + \ ( a \ - \ 8)·(\sqrt3) \ + \ ( 2a \ - \ 13 ) \ \ = \ \ 0    $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \  ( a \ - \ 5)·(\sqrt3) \ + \ ( 2a \ - \ 10 ) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ .    $$
This can be solved consistently by $ \ \mathbf{a = 5} \ \ ; $ as this is a linear equation in $ \ a \ \ , $ the solution is unique. (The last line, understandably, comes out looking like the result from **steven gregory's** synthetic division.)

[Note that this incidentally shows that $ \ 2 - \sqrt3 \ $ is also a zero of the polynomial, since $ \ u \ = \ -\sqrt3 \ $ produces $ \ ( 5 \ - \ a)·(\sqrt3) \ + \ ( 2a \ - \ 10 ) \ \ = \ \ 0 \   $ and the same solution for $ \ a \ \ . $  **Alan Abraham's** discovery of the third zero as $ \ x = 1 \ \rightarrow \ u = -1 \ $ yields
$$  -1 \ + \ 1  \ + \ ( a \ - \ 8)·(-1) \ + \ ( 2a \ - \ 13 ) \ \ = \ \ 0  \ \   \Rightarrow \ \   a \ - \ 5 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ .  ]  $$